# Add a class to links with title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So I'm creating a site to my client, and I'm designing the sub menus. My problem is that the sub menu links only contain title and href, and this isn't working for me.

*JS*

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').removeClass("valittu");
$('a [title="Taaperokurssi"]).addClass("valittu");
});
</script>
```

*HTML*

```
<a title="Taaperokurssi" href="xxx">Taaperokurssi</a>
<a title="Junnukurssi" href="xxx">Junnukurssi</a>
<a title="Yhteiseloa myötäkarvaan" href="xxx">Yhteiseloa myötäkarvaan</a>
<a title="Lapsi ja koira" href="xxx">Lapsi ja koira</a>
<a title="Pentutoko" href="http://hurttiajahuumoria.fi/kurssit/sujuva-arki/pentutoko">Pentutoko</a>
<a title="Aktivoi tokolla" href="xxx">Aktivoi tokolla</a>
<a title="Rallytoko" href="xxx">Rallytoko</a>
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUSgd/1/).

I thought that I could use CSS selectors with jQuery?

I have jQuery included, that shouldn't be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `a` and `[`. Having the space means to select the descendants of a tag with title attribute is `Taaperokurssi`.

```
$('a[title="Taaperokurssi"]').addClass("valittu");
```

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen You even didn't load jQuery, how would it work?http://jsfiddle.net/LUSgd/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code, you have missed the `)` for your *document* selector also you should remove the space between your selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //  -----^
     $('a').removeClass("valittu");
     $('a[title="Taaperokurssi"]').addClass("valittu");
 //  ----^
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5Ymf/

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen That's because you haven't loaded jQuery. You are loading mootools.